# A simple Java Race Condition

Tags: java, race-condition

I just wanted to write an example for an race condition:

**MyParallelClass.java**:

```java
public class MyParallelClass implements java.lang.Runnable {
    public int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (test.globalVar > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                counter++;
            }
            test.globalVar--;
        }
    }
}
```

**test.java**:

```java
public class test {
    public static int globalVar;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        globalVar = 1;

        MyParallelClass a = new MyParallelClass();
        MyParallelClass b = new MyParallelClass();

        new Thread(a).start(); // Thread A
        new Thread(b).start(); // Thread B

        System.out.println(globalVar);
    }
}
```

**What I thought would happen:**

I thought this could output either `0` if thread A was executed completely before Thread B starts.

The variable `test.globalVar` could also get manipulated like this:

```
Thread A                     -  Thread B  
checks if (globalVar > 0)
      looping ...               checks if (globalVar > 0)
      looping ...               execute all four bytecode commands of "test.globalVar--;"
      execute test.globalVar--;
```

so the value of `test.globalVar` would be `-1`.

So either one of the if-statements get executed or both.

**What actually happened:**

I got `0` and `1` as output of the main method. Why do I get `0` and `1` and not `0` and `-1`?

Comment: Sequence of thread execution is not guaranteed. It is on operating system mercy.

Comment: What do you mean by I got 0 and 1? Are you trying to print globalVar out somewhere else besides main's System.out.println(globalVar)?

Comment: try joining both of the threads before printing globalVar. You're probably reaching the last line of the main method before both threads have a chance to finish. If 1 finishes you end up with 0, if neither finishes before you get there you get 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
System.out.println(globalVar);
```

does not wait for the threads to complete. The threads may or may not be complete at that point. So the value can be `0`, `1`, or `-1` depending on whether both the threads completed, one completed or both did not complete.

To have a better test,
 - use `Thread.sleep()` in the threads to make sure that there is a delay
 - Use different delays in the different threads to better visualize the race condition.
 - You may want to print the value of the variable in the threads also. this way you have three threads racing (A, B and the main thread) and you get better visualizations.

Answer (score 3):

You are decrementing `globalVar` twice. The possible values of `globalVar` at the end are:

- `-1` - if everything went fine and both threads correctly decremented the value before it was printed
- `0`:

  - if only one thread managed to decrement the variable and the second one didn't manage to finish before printing it
  - if the `globalVar` was decremented at the same time
- `1`:

  - if `System.out.println()` managed to execute before both threads completed (quite probable). The `globalVar` was indeed modified, but after it was already printed
  - due to visibility issue `main` thread sees original `globalVar` value, not the one modified by different threads. You need some sort of synchronization or `volatile` keyword to see changes made by other threads immediately (or ever).

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  I think you need to run more tests. :-)

You might try changing your loop in the Runnable class to sleep with a random number of milliseconds (500-1000).  Loop just 10 times.  See if you don't get your expected race condition.

I think that most computers are just too darn fast.  You're simple loop may not be doing enough work to cause a thread switch.

I love these kinds of questions because I run into bugs like this all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a 1 if the value is printed before either thread has decremented the value.